# Add bootstrap tooltip in input field

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip, joomla3.0, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using Bootstrap 4 on my website. Need to add tooltips for some elements. It's not so difficult, but I have problems with tooltips fir input fields.

This is example for one input field
HTML Code:

```
<div class="col">
   <div class="field_item is-label-hide">
      <input data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" name="<?php echo $form->getName(); ?>[newprize][0][title]" id="prizeTitle" title="Название должно интриговать, но соответствовать тому, что вы разыгрываете." type="text" value="" valid-field="1" placeholder="Название приза"/>
      <label>Название приза</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#prizeTitle").tooltip({
            trigger:'focus', 
            title: 'Название должно интриговать, но соответствовать тому, что вы разыгрываете.'
        });
    });
```

My website use Joomla 3. But all tooltips works, but in input doesn't work.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Do they work if you add `data-container="body"` to the element? Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve].

Comment: Doesn't work...